# How to enable extended logging for classic asp on IIS7 on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp-classic

I had to deploy an application that was not written by me onto the above configuration. It is a rather bizarre hybrid of asp.net and classic asp and it's the classic asp that is proving troublesome.

The client is having problems with 500 Internal Server Errors appearing and I can see some of these in the logs but I only get the error code and the page name but little else.

What I would like to see is the actual error message to at least give me an idea *what* is going on (or not going on, depending on your point of view)

I don't want to display errors in the browser as I don't know the code well enough and this could (for all I know) display some crazy code where the db password is hard-coded into the site.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the ASP properties for your site. Under "Debugging Properties" there are 2 settings that are relevant to your situation:

- Enable Log Error Requests - if set to True this should cause all errors to be written to your IIS log and to the client browser
- Log Errors to NT Log - if set to True this will cause all errors to be written to the Windows Event log

I believe the ASP config section is (by default) locked from editing at the site level. You will either need to make the changes server-wide, or unlock the setting first.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/asp

Comment: Enable Log Error requests was enabled already yet it just says '500' with no line number etc. I *did* enable NT logging so hopefully this will show me the actual problem! Perhaps the problem is not in the code?

Comment: make sure to restart IIS